# blackberry alternate entry point- start app from background application(on push message click)

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I want to open my UI app from a background application. How its done ?.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("MYAPP") ){
      theApp = new App();
      theApp.enterEventDispatcher();  ///this  is my ui class
   }
   else {
      BackgroundApplication app = new BackgroundApplication();
      app.setupBackgroundApplication();
      app.enterEventDispatcher();  ///this is a background application listen for push notifications
   }
}
```

When I get a push notification, the `BackgroundApplication` should alert a popup.
When I click the popup, I want it to open the UI screen. How is this done? I tried this:

```
int modHandle = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("MYAPP");
     ApplicationDescriptor[] apDes = CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(modHandle);
     try {
        ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(apDes[0]);
     } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But it's not opening the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass argument "MYAPP" to code that's running application:

```
ApplicationDescriptor[] appDescriptors =
CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(
        CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("MYAPP"));//.Cod file name
ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor(
appDescriptors[0], new String[] {"MYAPP"});
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(appDescriptor);
```

Read more [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/How_To_-_Launch_a_third-party_application_from_another_third-party_application.html?nodeid=1094023&vernum=0)

Comment: what are "param1", "param2", "param3", "param4" ?

Comment: what is "yourMDSRuntimeCodFileName" . same as "MYAPP" ?

Comment: is it possible to push a specific page on the app ?

Comment: @JaneRaj this is your cod filename without ".cod" extension (probably "MYAPP")

Comment: @Signare you could pass any arguments that you want. So app during startup could determine which screen to show

Comment: @EugenMartynov if i have a home.java class is in the app. i want to push that page. so i have to give like this ? ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor(
appDescriptors[0], new String[] {"home"}); ?

Comment: @Signare and also add code to application like `if ("home".equals(arg[0])) app.pushScreen(new Home())`