# Blackberry - How to transfer data from background to main ui application

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

Iam using push notification to show notification. Its working fine by Alternate Entry point. Background application will listen for notifications. When I click on a notification, I want to open a specific page on my UI application. How is it done? I tried using the following code, but it will alway load the Ui from the starting page. How can I load a specific page if the app is already running. Else load the UI from the begining page.  Also I want to pass some values from the Background app to the UI Application.

```java
try {
     ApplicationDescriptor[] appDescriptors = 
         CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("MYAPP"));
     ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = 
         new ApplicationDescriptor(appDescriptors[0], new String[] {"MYAPP"});
     ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(appDescriptor);
} catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **already** transferring data from the background to the main UI Application (the string `"MYAPP"`).

Your application (the one [listed in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555165/blackberry-alternate-entry-point-start-app-from-background-applicationon-push)) starts up, and checks the arguments passed to it, and then determines whether to run in the background, or as a normal UI Application.

You can just add **more** arguments.  In the code above, change it to something like this:

```java
ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = 
     new ApplicationDescriptor(appDescriptors[0], 
                               new String[] { "MYAPP", "4", "FirstScreen" });
```

Then, in your `UiApplication` subclass (e.g. in App.java), you can change it to

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Application theApp = null;

    switch (args.length) {
    case 2:
        // initial screen and number of notifications provided
        theApp = new App(args[2]);
        app.setNumberOfNotificationsReceived(Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        break;
    case 1: 
        // just the number of notifications was provided, not an initial screen name
        theApp = new App();
        app.setNumberOfNotificationsReceived(Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        break;
    case 0:
    default:
        // no arguments .. launch the background application
        BackgroundApplication app = new BackgroundApplication();
        app.setupBackgroundApplication();
        theApp = app;
        break;
    }

    theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
}
```

... where I've added the `setNumberOfNotificationsReceived()` method and the `App(String)` constructor in your `App` class.  Those are just examples.  Make them whatever you want.

App.java:

```java
public App()
{        
    // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
    pushScreen(new DefaultScreen());
} 

public App(String screenName) {
    if (screenName.equalsIgnoreCase("FirstScreen")) {
        pushScreen(new FirstScreen());
    } else {
        pushScreen(new DefaultScreen());
    }
}
```