# How to make a blackberry application start , by code?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, push-notification, blackberry-jde

I have a background function listening for push messages. I need to handle though the push. I created the function to take any actions when the push arrives and it works pretty well. For example when a push arrives i increment a number etc etc.

However what would be the code to actually make the application start , when the user presses ok to the push?

I just need to make the application start normally , like the user just pressed on the icon of the app.

```
I am using OS < 7.X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this - 
When you click the ok button use the following code to run your ui application.

```
public void dialogClosed(Dialog dialog, int choice) {
      switch (choice) {
          case Dialog.OK: 
              try {

                  ApplicationDescriptor[] appDescriptors =CodeModuleManager.getApplicationDescriptors(CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("BlackBerryCity"));    //here BlackBerryCity is the COD module Name
                  ApplicationDescriptor appDescriptor = new ApplicationDescriptor(appDescriptors[0], new String[] {"BlackBerryCity"});
                  ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(appDescriptor);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              break;
          case Dialog.CANCEL:

              break;
          default:
              break;
       }
   }
```

Comment: It looks like you may have got this general technique [from this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11556939/119114), but you would only need to pass `"cod module name of your application"` as a String argument if the `main(String[])` function was expecting `"cod module name of your application"`.  In the question I link to, it was, but in general, I would guess that most people don't have it coded that way.  It just needs to be consistent, of course.

Comment: Rather than getting the app descriptor from the module, you can simply create a new ApplicationDesciptor from the currentApplicationDescriptor property. I am assuming that the code that is listening for the push is in the same module as the app to be launched.

Answer (score 3):

One typical pattern is to build an application that has two *entry points*.  That is, it can be started in two different ways.  One way, would be the normal `UiApplication`.  That's the standard BlackBerry app that can be started with a home screen icon press.

The other way would be to define a background service, that handles push notifications, and is started by the OS as soon as the device boots.

You'll define the background/push entry point by adding an **Alternate Entry Point** in your app's BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.  Make sure to check **Auto-run at Startup** and **Do not display the application icon ...**.  Your app descriptor xml file should then contain something like this, in addition to the normal entry point for the UiApplication:

```
  <AlternateEntryPoints>
    <AlternateEntryPoint Title="PushService" MainMIDletName="" 
                         ArgumentsForMain="-push" HomeScreenPosition="0"
                         StartupTier="7" IsSystemModule="true" 
                         IsAutostartup="true" hasTitleResource="false" 
                         TitleResourceBundleKey="" TitleResourceBundleName="" 
                         TitleResourceBundleClassName="" TitleResourceBundleRelativePath="">
      <Icons/>
      <KeywordResources KeywordResourceBundleName="" KeywordResourceBundleRelativePath="" KeywordResourceBundleClassName="" KeywordResourceBundleKey=""/>
    </AlternateEntryPoint>
  </AlternateEntryPoints>
```

Then, you'll have a main program like this:

```
public class MyApp extends UiApplication

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-push")) {
          // this is the push service
          PushAgent pa = new PushAgent();
          pa.enterEventDispatcher();
       } else {
          // UiApplication
          MyApp app = new MyApp();
          app.enterEventDispatcher();
       }
    }
}
```

Where `PushAgent` is a class that `extends Application`, not `UiApplication`.

Then, when your push agent receives a notification and you decide you want to show the UI, use something like this:

```java
ApplicationDescriptor ad = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
// String[] used for command line args, but we don't pass any to the UI app
ApplicationDescriptor ui = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, new String[] { });
ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ui);
```

Comment: What is the ApplicationDescriptor and why do i get on error on it? Even if i put the .xml name gets me an error.

Comment: @donparalias, are you talking about the `ApplicationDescriptor` **class**, or the `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` **file**?  Those are different things.  The last 4 lines in my answer are Java code to use, to launch the UI app.  The BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml is a configuration file of sorts for your app.   This is normally generated by the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin when you create a new project.  It's usually at the root of your project, on your hard disk.

Comment: I mean the last 4 lines. Ok the errors where cause i wasnt importing some classes , and didnt use a try. but even now that i do , it doesnt start my application.

Comment: @donparalias, is your `main(String[])` method coded up the way mine is above?  It needs to be.  That code relies on having two separate entry points in the same application.  The same `main(String[])` method must handle both the background launch, and the UI app launch.  The background (push) service will get run by passing `-push` as an argument, and the UI app gets started if there are no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
class EntryPointForApplication extends UiApplication {

    private static EntryPointForApplication theApp;

    public EntryPointForApplication() { 
        GUIApplication scr = new GUIApplication(); 
        pushScreen(scr);         
    } 

}
```

Read this also [How to setup alternate entry point in Blackberry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921029/how-to-setup-alternate-entry-point-in-blackberry-application)

Comment: What is the use of the static member?

Comment: @adwiv  if you see the link i shared you will come to know how its using in further (in main method there )

Comment: I think the way it is being used in the shared link is totally useless and based on incorrect understanding of how BB processes work. Static objects in BB are limited to the process - they are not shared between different app instances. The main method runs exactly once for each app instance, so the check for theApp being null will always succeed.

Comment: I read that and am saying that the description there is wrong :-) Whether or not you use that static variable, you will NEVER get multiple instances under normal circumstances. Try that yourself. And under abnormal circumstances, the static variable will not prevent creation of a new instance.

Comment: He is right. The static variable will be created twice and have 2 seperate and unrelated values. Static variables will not be shared across both instances of the app, even if you use alternate entry points. This code is just going to be misleading to anyone who tries to use it uninformed

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness here are all the options that you can use to launch an application:

I am assuming that you already have multiple entry points - one for the background listener and one for the UI Application. Also assuming that you are not passing any Application Arguments for the UI App. (See Nate's answer for full description of how to do this.)

1. Using `runApplication()` method:

   ```
   ApplicationDescriptor ad = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
   // String[] used for command line args, but we don't pass any to the UI app
   ApplicationDescriptor ui = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, new String[] { });
   //Launch the application and ask it to come in foreground
   ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().runApplication(ui, true);
   ```
2. Using `launch()` method:

   ```
   String modulename = "mymodule";
   ApplicationManager.launch(modulename);
   ```
3. Using `launchApplication()` method:

   ```
   String modulename = "mymodule";
   ApplicationManager.launchApplication(modulename);
   ```

One thing to note is that if your UI app is already open, all these methods will simply bring it to foreground in whatever condition it it. If you require the click of button to open a new instance of your app, you will have to pass some random parameter as the application arguments and then ignore it in the main method.